# How common is flipped classroom type teaching?

Tags: teaching, university, course-design

Flipped classroom teaching has become gradually more popular and studies show that the effectiveness of learning is better than in traditional lecture type courses. I've tried to give feedback to my own university after courses that this should be pursued, but so far there has been no changes here.

I'd like to know what percentage of courses are using flipped classrooms and how it varies between geographical location and subject/field. I would assume that fields with complex systems to learn would have greater benefits using flipped type compared to traditional lectures.

Comment: What exactly is a "flipped classroom"?

Comment: The "flipped classroom" is not as new of a concept as one might be led to believe -- ever had an assignment that required you to learn general explanations for yourself, and _office hours_ would concentrate on clarifying your questions? (This is how pretty much all of the engineering courses I've ever taken and have taught are ran.)

Comment: "effectiveness of learning is better" ... needs reference.

Comment: @GEdgar [The jury seems to still be out.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/medu.13272)

Comment: The implicit blanket premise that mathematics courses (e.g., in the U.S.) do not have a large component of responding to student questions is not correct. Nor the apparent premise that students do not do any prior or subsequent preparation outside of class. Etc.

Comment: @PeterK. at least this study about flipped classroom effectiveness in engineering in quite consistent https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/bjet.12548

Comment: Surprisingly I have discovered that graduate students, when asked in a survey, prefer to have traditional lectures by a wide margin. To me, lecturing remains a very inefficient way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The question explicitly asked is not that suitable for this forum. There is a answerable question hidden however: How to encourage a specific teaching style in a university?

Just "giving feedback to the university" will achieve exactly nothing. Universities are huge bureaucratic monsters with immense inertia build in. What you can do depends on your role in the university:

If you are teaching, then lead by example. In the universities I have been at there always was a department aimed at improving the quality of university teaching, and these are your natural allies. Contact them. Maybe they can broker contact with other teachers who want to do this or are already doing this. If you reach a critical mass, beautiful things can happen.

If you are a student then your options are fairly limited.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was really more interested on what I actually asked. How can I alter my question to be on topic if it is not? I thought this would be under 'University-level pedagogy'.

Comment: I know you're trying to be helpful, but this is not an answer to the question.  Perhaps you should ask the question that you are trying to answer, and post this as an answer there.